# Do swift chars relate to clang chars?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Swift's `String.Index` is defined in the docs as

> A position of a character or code unit in a string.

The `endIndex` is

> A string’s “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater
>   than the last valid subscript argument.

and `startIndex` is

> The position of the first character in a nonempty string.

**Is it correct to think of Swift chars in the context of C lang chars?**

My understanding in Clang is that the index of a character in a string returns the memory space of the character and the string ends on a null character.

So for Swift, the `endIndex` is the null character and the reason we use `String.Index` instead of using subscript String with an Int (something like `string[0]` like in say JavaScript) is because we are handling the memory space of the character.

If this is the right thinking is this because Swift runs on top of Objective-C runtime?

Comment: See https://flawlessapp.io/blog/dive-deep-into-swift-string/ for a good explanation of Swift strings

Comment: “Clang” is a compiler, you probably mean “C language.” – And no, a Swift `Character` is quite different from a C `char`. More resources: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html (look for “Unicode Representations of Strings”), https://oleb.net/blog/2017/11/swift-4-strings/, https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=30.